# R functions: why expressions can't be evaluated within return?

Tags: r

```
f=function(x){return(list(y=x, z = y))}; f(1)
```

I wonder why the above function does not work. Thank you very much!

Comment: `y` has no definition. this won't work outside the function either `list(y=1, z = y)`. `y` is the _name_ of an element in a list.

Comment: It's pointless and will make your code ugly, but if you really insist on making this a one liner, you can write `list(y = (y <- x), z = y)`. or, even uglier, `\`[<-\`(l <- list(y = x), 'z', l[['y']])`. i see no reason not to write `list(y = x, z = x)`

Comment: Try `f <- function(x) within.list(y <- x, z <- y)[c('y', 'z')]`

Comment: I've seen code that looks like this: `f=function(x){return(list(y <- x, z <- y))}; f(1)`, and I think the `return` is redundant. Try:  `f=function(x){ list(y <- x, z <- y)}; f(1)`

Comment: @42- the output of `list(y <- x, z <- y)` is unnamed. depends on what you are trying to accomplish i suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the arguments of the function `list` cannot "see" each other, so the statement `z = y` cannot "see" `y = x`.

This remembers me of the difference of `let` and `let*` in Lisp languages.
`let` does local assignments for local variables. They can't "see" each other. But `let*` makes the following assignments be able to "see" the previous assignments.

Why not doing:

```
f=function(x){y <- x; return(list(y = x, z = y))}; f(1)
```